# Best way to store a user token in Ruby script

Tags: ruby, windows, unix, token, credentials

I am developing a Ruby script designed for CLI which is based on a REST API. This API needs a token as credentials in order to recognize the user and allows him to retrieve his informations.
For now, this scripts asks the 30-length token in the console every time it is launched.

Now I'd like to store this token to avoid asking it every time the user wants to use the script. I don't know what the best way is, do I have to create a hidden file, containing the token, or ask the user to store it in an environment variable ?

I wanted to use the environment variable solution, but I don't know if it will work the same way for Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compose all approaches. Something like this:

```
def get_my_token()
  if ENV["MY_TOKEN"]
    return ENV["MY_TOKEN"]
  end

  token_path = File.expand_path("~/.my_token") # will be expanded to user's home (Documents or smth) in windows, check it yourself as I don't have running windows around here
  if File.exists?(token_path)
    return File.read(token_path).strip
  end  

  # resort to asking user for token here
end
```

ENV should go first - so you'll be able to override your config if needed for some testing purpose. Also note that you can run your script as `MY_TOKEN=xxxx ruby my_app.rb` as well.